# Is there a way to "listen" for changes in a Lua table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

This is purely an interest based question.

Is there some way to listen/monitor a Lua table and see if changes are made to it and then call a function when a new entry is added to said table?

In other words,

```lua
local t = {}

local function listener()
    print( "new entry added" )
end

t.text = "Hello!"
```

Are there some methods, functions or other means that I can do to call a specific function as soon as something has been added to a table.

I don't merely want to use a timer to constantly loop through the table every few seconds or milliseconds.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a section in Programming in Lua that covers this problem.

[Programming in Lua: 13.4.4 – Tracking Table Accesses](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html)

This entails the use of metatables to modify the basic behavior of a table. Specifically we need to modify what happens when we set a table value and get a value from the table, these are the bare minimum to create the behavior you are looking for.

The above link has a great example, here is one for the code in your question:

```
local function listener(k,v)
  print( "new entry added: \n\tKey = " .. k .. "\n\tValue = " .. v)
end
local metaTable

do
  local protectedTable = {}
  metaTable = {
    __index = function (t,k)
      return protectedTable[k]
    end,
    __newindex = function (t,k,v)
      protectedTable[k] = v   -- update original table
      listener(k,v)
    end
  }
end

local t = setmetatable({},metaTable)

t.text = "Hello!"
print(t.text)
```

Something to keep in mind, this method will not allow you to use `pairs` on `t` as it is an empty table and I did not define `__pairs` in the metatable in my example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to listen for changes.
Specifically, [use the metatable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4).

`__newindex` is the metafunction you want if you are only interested in new entries, not changed ones.

If you also want notification on changes, you need `__index`, `__pairs` as well, as you must not store the entries in the table itself.

Comment: Worth noting that `__index` does not help detect if a field is changed it. `__index` is only called if the indexed value is absent from the table. https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html

Comment: @Nifim Maybe I was not cleat enough about *why* `__index` and `__pairs` would be needed. Elaborated.