# How to use metatables to monitor changes made to an embedded table? (Lua)

Tags: lua, metatable

I am looking to monitor changes made to one particular embedded table, in this case *oranges*, using the __newindex metamethod. My current code is able to detect the change, yet the value will obviously not update. I understand that the original data needs a proxy table in order to use the __newindex metamethod for detecting value changes.

```
local data = {cherries = {quantity = 0}, oranges = {quantity = 0}}
local _data = data
data.oranges = {}

local metaTable = {
    __newindex = function (_, key, value)
        print("Updating " .. tostring(key) .. " to " .. tostring(value))
        _data[key] = value
    end
}

setmetatable(data.oranges, metaTable)

data.oranges.quantity = 1 -- Invokes "Updating quantity to 1"
print(data.oranges.quantity) -- "nil" (I would like it to print 1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to "listen" for changes in a Lua table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598440/is-there-a-way-to-listen-for-changes-in-a-lua-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an *index* metamethod:

```
local metaTable = {
    __newindex = function (_, key, value)
        print("Updating " .. tostring(key) .. " to " .. tostring(value))
        _data[key] = value
    end,
    __index = function (_, key, value)
        return data[key]
    end
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, would there be a way to create a proxy of data.oranges without erasing the existing entries inside the table?